# how to get value of colors from CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I define Color in CSS file

```
 .level1 {
color: ["#7FFF00", "#00CA9A", "#2CB371", "#124B21","#006400"];
}
  .level2 {
color: ["#7FFF01", "#00FA8A", "#1CB371", "#328B22","#006400"];
 }
```

Now I want to read those color from the javascript JS file

```
   var color = $(".level1").css("color");
   var color2 = $(".level2").css("color");
```

and I got null in color
Could you explain me what I did wrong ?

Did the define of the colors are correct ?

Comment: Am I being stupid or is this css all wrong?

Comment: Can't put arrays in CSS, at least not for the `color` attribute

Comment: I am new in the CSS how I need to define the CSS ?

Comment: Start [here](http://www.csstutorial.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your color declaration is syntactically wrong. You are trying to declare something that looks like an array of colors, which isn't supported in CSS. The browser will ignore rules it cannot understand, therefor the colors does not get applied.

Since it doesn't get applied, jQuery cannot find a value for the color-property of that element, thus returning null.

If you fix the color declaration, providing only a single color:

```
.level1 {
    color: #7FFF00;
}
```

Your jQuery code will work just fine.

Comment: is it possible to define only one color ?

Comment: You SHOULD be defining only one color

Comment: @user1365697 Sorry, I missed to remove the quotation marks you had around the color value. Try again now!

Comment: when I call to $(".orderLevel1") I got []

Comment: @user1365697 If you call only `$(".orderLevel1")` you will get back an array of elements that match that selector. If no element match that selector (have a class `orderLevel1`), an empty array will be returned. Which seems to be the case here.

Answer (score 4):

CSS drops rules and values it doesn't recognize, so you can't store arbitrary data in stylesheets.

Comment: Don't store data in CSS.  CSS is for style.

Comment: What do the four colors mean?  An element can only have one color.